# PyAiml :: Condition Tag of AIML not getting parsed using Python

Tags: python-2.7, chatbot, aiml

The below is the sample AIML file:

```
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<aiml version = "1.0.1" encoding = "UTF-8">
<category>
<pattern>DO YOU FIND ME ATTRACTIVE</pattern>
<template>
  <condition name="gender">
    <li value="male">I find you very handsome.</li>
    <li value="female">I find you very pretty.</li>
    <li>I find you very attractive.</li>
  </condition>
</template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

The below is the simple python code:

```
            category = "DO YOU FIND ME ATTRACTIVE"
            bot.setPredicate("gender", "male") ## Setting the Predicate
            reply = bot.respond(category)
```

**Ask**:

When the user provide a value to gender, I want my python code to set the value of gender as "male" and then give an appropriate reply.

**Problem**:

It is not able to set predicate and from their reply with appropriate comment. I am getting reply as "I find you very attractive" instead of "I find you very handsome". In general, if I use set Predicate without the condition tag it works. So, can you let me know if the problem is with parsing condition tag or the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your AIML file as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="1.0">
<category>
    <pattern>DO YOU FIND ME * ATTRACTIVE</pattern>
    <template>
        What is your gender ?
        <think><set name="topic">GENDER</set></think>
        <br/>In case you dont mind?
    </template>
</category>
<topic name="GENDER">
    <category>
        <pattern>MALE</pattern>
        <that>* CASE YOU *</that>
        <template>I find you very handsome.!</template>
    </category>
    <category>
        <pattern>FEMALE</pattern>
        <that>* CASE YOU *</that>
        <template>I find you very pretty!</template>
    </category>
</topic>
</aiml>
```

Comment: "that" tag also dont work with Python & AIML ie. it can't parse "that" tag, same was the problem with "condition" tag.

Comment: You need to check the version of Python you are using.
AIML is verified till Python 3.5 , however in case you are using heigher version, you can try downgrading to 3.5 and check again.

Hope it solves the parsing issue !

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and AIML 1.0

Comment: Find a working fiddle for AIML <that> tag
[Working Fiddle](https://repl.it/repls/HuskyConfusedArchaeocete)